# Return to shinyproxy login page after inactivity

Tags: r, docker, shinyproxy

I’m using simple authentication and running ShinyProxy in a Docker container.

I notice that after logging in if I leave the tab open but do not interact with the tab for some time (30 min will do it), upon returning to the tab and clicking on an app I am returned to the login page. I think this behavior is also related to an issue I am having with data.tables in my shiny apps not functioning after some period of inactivity but the rest of the app works.

I don’t think this issue of being logged out after inactivity is related to the hearbeat-timeout (which I have set to 21600 minutes). Is there another explanation? I don’t want the user to be logged out after inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

This github issue provided a workaround:
https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy/issues/137

Specifically, adding the following to the application.yml file solved my issue:

```
server:
  servlet.session.timeout: 0
```